# How to prevent login until user verified by the admin in Firebase?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing android  native application using android studio and firebase. i did admin panel website for the client app. user have to register the client app usually  but they have to  wait until the admin verification. how to do it ?

Comment: In login api response, return whether user is approved for login or not. If approved, then proceed with login

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about what problems you're seeing if you want a good answer. Have you read the firebase SDK docs? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

Comment: thank you for your response .but the main thing is user uses mobile application to register their account. what i want is when user registers their account through the client mobile app, after the registration they have to wait until the user verified by the admin. in other words admin have to give the approval for the login for new registered users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent a user declared in the Auth service to be able to login, the most straightforward way is to disable his account.

With the Admin SDK you can create users that are initially disabled. For example, with the Admin SDK for Node.js:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'user@example.com',
  password: 'secretPassword',
  disabled: true
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?authuser=0#create_a_user) for more details. So you could implement that in a Cloud Function that your admin panel website calls for creating a new user.

Then in a app/module dedicated to the Admin users, you would call another Cloud Function that would [update the user record](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?authuser=0#update_a_user) in order to activate a user, as follows:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  disabled: false
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error updating user:', error);
  });
```

---

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

#### Update following your comment

If your users register themselves from the app, you should note that on successful account creation **they are immediately logged in** (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-taskauthresult-createuserwithemailandpassword-string-email,-string-password)).

In this case, the classical solution is to use a Custom Claim which indicates if the user has been approved/verified by the Admin.

If the user holds this Custom Claim you show him the corresponding application screens. If not, you can, for example, display a message or/and sign them out and send them back to the login screen... (it’s up to you to define the exact flow). In parallel, you write your Securities Rules for Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc based on the Claim. See the [Custom Claims documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) for more details on how to implement that.

Comment: thank you for your response .but the main thing is  user uses mobile application to register their account. what i want is when user registers their account through the client mobile app, after the registration  they have to wait until the user verified by the admin. in other words admin have to give the approval for the login  for new registered users.